# How do I find the version of Sun Studio 11 installed on my Solaris 10 server?

Tags: solaris, c++, solaris-10

When I do :

pkginfo | grep SPROapplication SPROatd,

it only shows me Sun Studio 12. But, the installer( a Rogue wave library installer) I am using detects Sun Studio 11 as well on the server. But, am not able to find what version of it is installed. Or, if it is installed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sun Studio, there is a 'version' command included.  Run it with no arguments and it will tell you the version of the product.  You can also figure out which version of Studio is installed by checking the version of a component (like the C compiler) using "cc -V" and then using this chart to find the version of the product. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/training/index-jsp-141991.html.

The installer may be using your search path, or it may be checking known locations for binaries.  Or it might be guessing wrong about the version.  Default installation typically go into /opt/SUNWspro.  That's a good place to look for binaries.

Any packages whose names start with SPRO are likely to be parts of Sun Studio (now Solaris Studio).